# Meu arquivo _Layout.cshtml não esta sendo reconhecido na aplicação, o que fazer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, layout

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em MVC asp.net, e do nada a minha aplicação não reconhece mais o arquivo de layout não estando mais aplicando o bootstrap e o jquery... Como consigo resolver isso??

Meu arquivo layout esta assim:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Aplicação Teste</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Nome do aplicativo", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    @if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                    {
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Início", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Relatorios", "Relatorios", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Cadastros", "Cadastros", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contato", "Contatos", "Home")</li>
                    }

                    @if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Premium"))
                    {
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Início", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sobre", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contato", "Contatos", "Home")</li>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sobre", "About", "Home")</li>

                    }

                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Projeto Andrêy Ferraz</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-3.3.1.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap.js")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Ao carregar a página e aperta F12 apareceu os seguintes erros:

```
GET http://localhost:49866/bundles/jquery-3.3.1.js net::ERR_ABORTED
GET http://localhost:49866/bundles/bootstrap.js net::ERR_ABORTED
GET http://localhost:49866/bundles/jquery-3.3.1.js net::ERR_ABORTED
GET http://localhost:49866/bundles/bootstrap.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Verificou os caminhos das bibliotecas? Verifique sua pergunta, está confusa.

Comment: Confusa, não entendi... veja bem, vou editar a pergunta e colocar o código de como está o meu layout... isso aconteceu parece que após eu atualizar as bibliotecas Jquery e bootstrap!!

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "não reconhece"?

Comment: @LINQ quando eu executo a aplicação ela não carrega as renderizações corretas do bootstrap e jquery, ou seja, a página fica como se não existisse CSS na mesma, toda desconfigurada!!

Comment: Verifica se está mostrando alguma mensagem de erro ao carregar a página. Aperta F12.

Comment: @EmanuelF vou editar a pergunta e colocar o erro que apareceu

Comment: Você alterou no arquivp Bundle o caminho para essa nova versão do jquery?

Comment: Confere esse artigo: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn168847.aspx

Comment: eu li e não ajudou em muita coisa, pois aparatemente está tudo ok

Comment: posta o seu BundleConfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para utilizar o bundle, não basta adicionar o caminho na sua `MasterPage` (_Layout.cstml) você precisa adicionar o seu mapeamento no `BundleConfig`

E aqui, você não deve chamar o script em específico, mas sim o seu bundle:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-3.3.1.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap.js")
```

Provavelmente o correto seria:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

> Aguardo o post do seu BundleConfig para melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Por incrivel que pareça sozinho voltou ao normal, provavelmente era problema no IIES e não na aplicação em si, agora esta funcionando normal!!!